# Why does std::is_invocable_r reject functions returning non-moveable types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, sfinae, type-traits

I'm curious about the definition of `std::is_invocable_r` and how it interacts with non-moveable types. Its libc++ implementation under clang in C++20 mode seems to be wrong based on my understanding of the language rules it's supposed to emulate, so I'm wondering what's incorrect about my understanding.

Say we have a type that can't be move- or copy-constructed, and a function that returns it:

```cpp
struct CantMove {
  CantMove() = default;
  CantMove(CantMove&&) = delete;
};

static_assert(!std::is_move_constructible_v<CantMove>);
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<CantMove>);

CantMove MakeCantMove() { return CantMove(); }
```

Then it's possible to call that function to initialize a `CantMove` object (I believe due to the copy elision rules):

```cpp
CantMove cant_move = MakeCantMove();
```

And the type traits agree that the function is invocable and returns `CantMove`:

```cpp
using F = decltype(MakeCantMove);
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<F>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<CantMove, std::invoke_result_t<F>>);
```

But `std::is_invocable_r` says it's *not* possible to invoke it to yield something convertible to `CantMove`, at least in C++20 under clang:

```
static_assert(!std::is_invocable_r_v<CantMove, F>);
```

---

The [definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.rel#lib:is_invocable_r) of `std::is_invocable_r` is

> The expression `INVOKE<R>(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand

with `INVOKE<R>` being [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/function.objects#func.require-2) as

> Define `INVOKE<R>(f, t1, t2, …, tN)` as [...] `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, …, tN)` implicitly converted to `R`.

and `INVOKE` [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/function.objects#func.require-1.7) (in this case) as simply `MakeCantMove()`. But the [definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#3) of whether an implicit conversion is possible says:

> An expression `E` can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=E;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` ([dcl.init]).

But we saw above that `CantMove cant_move = MakeCantMove();` is accepted by the compiler. **So is clang wrong about accepting this initialization, or is the implementation of `std::is_invocable_r_v` wrong?** Or is my reading of the standard wrong?

For the record, the reason I care about this question is that types like `std::move_only_function` (I'm using an advanced port to C++20 of this) have their members' overload sets [restricted](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.move.ctor#1) by `std::is_invocable_r_v`, and I'm finding that it's not possible to usefully work with functions that return a no-move type like this. Is that by design, and if so why?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Seems to [work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/vfGGo7dfx)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You need `-stdlib=libc++`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So is clang wrong about accepting this initialization, or is the
> implementation of `std::is_invocable_r_v` wrong?

This is a bug of libc++. In the [implementation of `is_invocable_r`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/58d9ab70aef3d7ad5b34c525afc430e122409054/libcxx/include/type_traits#L3514), it uses `is_convertible` to determine whether the result can be implicitly converted to `T`, which is incorrect since `is_convertible_v<T, T>` is `false` for non-movable types, in which case `std::declval` adds an rvalue reference to `T`.

It is worth noting that both [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91456) and [MSVC-STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1282) have bug reports about this issue, which have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks very much. I [filed a bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55346). I'm surprised to see that `std::is_convertible` doesn't match the language definition of an implicit conversion though. What's up with that?